# Is "to the point" formal enough to be written in an academic text?

Tags: phrase-usage, academic-writing

In the following text I used "to the point" to mean that some governments control people and this tendency to control causes the right of individual liberty be restricted. Is it natural to use this phrase in an academic text?

> The right of individual liberty is enshrined in the constitution, but many
> governments try to control people **to the point** that it restricts this
> fundamental right.

Comment: Yes, "to the point" is formal enough, and entirely natural in that sentence. It's not clear what "it" refers to though. "Governments" is plural and "control" is a verb, so neither can be the antecedent. Consider rephrasing to, "*... control people to the point **of restricting** this fundamental right*".